# Image popup on mouseover of li without hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I have a list and would like to have additional info (a graphic) pop up when someone mouses over the individual list items.  I thought I'd found the answer online, but this method works only on hyperlinks within `<li>` tags...and the problem is that I don't want to click through to the link...just have an image popup.  No link.

Anyone know how to do this?  I can modify the script I found to work with `<li>`s but then it can't show different images...I can insert a fixed image, but not have it choose different ones for each `<li>`.

Thanks for any suggestions or help!

Edit:  Here's the current Javascript I'm trying to modify -- does exactly what I want...only for links, not LI elements:

```
(written by Alen Grakalic (http://cssglobe.com))

$("a.preview").hover(function(e){
            this.t = this.title;
    this.title = "";    
    var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
    $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+ this.href +"' alt='Image preview' />"+ c +"</p>");                            
    $("#preview")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
        .fadeIn("fast");                        
},
function(){
    this.title = this.t;    
    $("#preview").remove();
});
$("a.preview").mousemove(function(e){
    $("#preview")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
});         
};

$(document).ready(function(){
imagePreview();
});
```

Comment: What mark-up are you working with, what have you tried? Please, show us some code. And a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you've got so far would be useful, too.

Comment: Here's the current thing I've got, in Javascript:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a href (or some other named) attribute to your LI tags, then access the image's url like this (example using href attribute):

```
$("li.preview").hover(function(e){
    this.t = this.title;
    this.title = "";    
    var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
    var $li = $(this);
    $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+ $li.attr("href") +"' alt='Image preview' />"+ c +"</p>");                            
    $("#preview")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
        .fadeIn("fast");                        
}
```